# Applying New Catalog Price Rule to Current Cart in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I created a new catalog price rule for customers in my "Wholesale" customer group. I assigned a customer to that group. The customer currently has items in their cart, but the prices of these items were not updated to reflect the new catalog price rule. Is there anyway to update the quoted prices of these products, without having the customer delete and re-add all the items to their cart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to the issue. If you go to Abandoned Carts, click on the Customer's cart, click create order, add the items to the order, then place them back in the customer's cart....the updated prices will now be reflected in the cart.